# Issue with indexing using two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I have two data frames `Table_1` and `Table_2` and I need to add a column `"index"` to `Table_2` where value 1 for matching rows from `Table_1` and 0 for others.

Basically, I need to match the "Pol", "CTY" ,"STATE" and "CRP" columns from Table_1 and "STATE", "CTY" , "CRP" and "Pol_No" from Table_2.

I prefer the data.table method.

```
 Table_1:

 Pol      Cty    Avg    STATE   CRP
 85010    23     1123    MO     11
 75022    23     1123    MO     11
 35014   143     450     MO     11
.
.

Table_2:

STATE   CTY    CRP   Pol_No   Plan   Price 
AL      1      11    150410   90     4563
AL      1      21    45023    90     5402
MO    143      11    85010    90     2522
.
.
```

Desired output as below.

```
Table_2:

STATE   CTY    CRP   Pol_No   Plan   Price  Index
AL      1      11    150410   90     4563     0
AL      1      21    45023    90     5402     0
MO    143      11    85010    90     2522     1
.
.
```

How can I achieve this is R.?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an entirely data.table solution:

```
 merge(t1,t2,by.x='Pol', by.y='Pol_No', all.y=TRUE)[,c('STATE.y','CTY', 'Cty', 'CRP.y',   'Pol',   'Plan',   'Price')]
#-----
   STATE.y CTY Cty CRP.y    Pol Plan Price
1:      AL   1  NA    21  45023   90  5402
2:      MO 143  23    11  85010   90  2522
3:      AL   1  NA    11 150410   90  4563
#--------
t3 <- merge(t1,t2,by.x='Pol', by.y='Pol_No', all.y=TRUE)[ ,
          c('STATE.y','CTY', 'Cty', 'CRP.y', 'Pol', 'Plan',   'Price')] 
t3[ , index := as.numeric(!is.na(Cty))]
t3
#--------
   STATE.y CTY Cty CRP.y    Pol Plan Price index
1:      AL   1  NA    21  45023   90  5402     0
2:      MO 143  23    11  85010   90  2522     1
3:      AL   1  NA    11 150410   90  4563     0
```

To get column names right after `merge(..` I first looked at:

```
merge(t1,t2,by.x='Pol', by.y='Pol_No', all.y=TRUE)
      Pol Cty  Avg STATE.x CRP.x STATE.y CTY CRP.y Plan Price
1:  45023  NA   NA    <NA>    NA      AL   1    21   90  5402
2:  85010  23 1123      MO    11      MO 143    11   90  2522
3: 150410  NA   NA    <NA>    NA      AL   1    11   90  4563
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a straight-forward multi-column join:

```
library(dplyr)
t2 %>%
  left_join(transmute(t1, CTY=Cty, STATE, Index=1L), by=c("CTY", "STATE")) %>%
  mutate(Index = if_else(is.na(Index), 0L, Index))
#   STATE CTY CRP Pol_No Plan Price Index
# 1    AL   1  11 150410   90  4563     0
# 2    AL   1  21  45023   90  5402     0
# 3    MO 143  11  85010   90  2522     1
```

**EDIT**

I've been trying to learn `data.table`, thought I'd give this a try. It feels a *little* clumsy to me, I'm sure there is a way to streamline it.

```
t1 <- setDT(t1); t2 <- setDT(t2)
```

For convenience, set the column names to be the same (I'm not sure how to make it happen easily otherwise) ... one is `"Cty"`, the other is `"CTY"`. Make them the same.

```
colnames(t1)[2] <- "CTY"
```

Now, the merge.

```
t1[,.(CTY,STATE,CRP,Index=1),][t2,on=c("CTY","STATE","CRP")]
#    CTY STATE CRP Index Pol_No Plan Price
# 1:   1    AL  11    NA 150410   90  4563
# 2:   1    AL  21    NA  45023   90  5402
# 3: 143    MO  11     1  85010   90  2522
```

Notes:

- the first bracket-op is selecting just the three joining columns and assigning the fourth, `Index`;
- the actual join is in the second bracket-op, the first is just a selection
- typically `data.table` ops work in side-effect, but not merges or selections like this, so it returns it without modifying the underlying structure; for this, we'll need to store it (back in `t2`, perhaps)

It's close ... now just update the `Index` field, since it's either `1` where the data co-exists or `NA` otherwise.

```
t2 <- t1[,.(CTY,STATE,CRP,Index=1),][t2,on=c("CTY","STATE","CRP")]
t2[,Index := as.integer(!is.na(Index)),]
t2
#    CTY STATE CRP Index Pol_No Plan Price
# 1:   1    AL  11     0 150410   90  4563
# 2:   1    AL  21     0  45023   90  5402
# 3: 143    MO  11     1  85010   90  2522
```

---

Data:

```
t1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
 Pol      Cty    Avg    STATE   CRP
 85010    23     1123    MO     11
 75022    23     1123    MO     11
 35014   143     450     MO     11')
t2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
STATE   CTY    CRP   Pol_No   Plan   Price 
AL      1      11    150410   90     4563
AL      1      21    45023    90     5402
MO    143      11    85010    90     2522')
```

Comment: This seems correct. CRP should also be considered when joining. But, I prefer the data.table method.

Comment: Nothing in your text, your data, or your code suggested that you are using or want to use `data.table`. Perhaps you should update your question. Sorry I omitted `CRP`, but frankly (1) it's trivial to add it to the `by=` argument and `transmute` call, and (2) if you want `data.table` then this answer goes away anyway.

Comment: I forgot to include in the text above. sorry that's my bad. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I had an amazing answer too but it only works with dataframes hah

Answer (score 0):

This is not a nice solution but it works for `data.table`. You need `sqldf` which works for dataframes and data tables.

```
library(data.table)
df1<-data.table(Pol=c(85010,75022,35014),Cty=c(23,23,143), Avg=c(1123,1123,450),STATE=c("MO","MO","MO"), CRP=c(11,11,11))

df2=data.table(STATE=c("AL","AL","MO"),CTY=c(1,1,143),CRP=c(11,21,11),Pol_No=c(150410,45023,85010),Plan=c(90,90,90),Price=c(4563,5402,2522))

library(sqldf)
#left join
df<-sqldf("select df2.STATE,df2.CTY,df2.CRP,df2.Pol_No,df2.Plan,df2.Price,df1.Pol from df2 left join df1 on df1.Pol=df2.Pol_No")
#create index
df$index<-ifelse(is.na(df$Pol),0,1)

#delete extra column
df$Pol<-NULL 

> df
  STATE CTY CRP Pol_No Plan Price index
1    AL   1  11 150410   90  4563     0
2    AL   1  21  45023   90  5402     0
3    MO 143  11  85010   90  2522     1
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't intend to edit yours and reversed it.